# the number of dots in each column of a dot diagram is completely determined if the number of dots in each row is known

Tags: linear-algebra

> (Chapter 7.2, Linear Algebra by Insel, Spence, Friedberg) Suppose that an array of dots (such as a dot diagram) has $k$ columns and $m$ rows and that the $j$ th column of the array contains $p_j$ dots and the $i$ th row of the array contains $r_i$ dots. If $p_1 \ge p_2 \ge ... \ge p_k$, prove the following:
>
> (a) $m = p_1$ and $k=r_1$
>
> (b) $p_j = \max\{i : r_i \ge j\}$ for $i \le j \le k$ and $r_i = \max\{j : p_j \ge i\}$ for $1 \le i \le m$. Hint: Use induction on $m$.
>
> (c) $r_1 \ge r_2 \ge ... \ge r_m$.
>
> (d) Conclude that the number of dots in each column of a dot diagram is completely determined if the number of dots in each row is known.

(a): $m < p_1$ is impossible. In addition, since $p_1$ is the column, which contains the largest number of dots, if $m>p_1$, then the row after the $p_1$th row is zero. Therefore, $m=p_1$.

(c) is true once we prove (b) given that $p_1 \ge ... \ge p_k$.

(d) also follows from (b).

I am struggling with the proof of $k=r_1$ and $(b)$. I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: Could you define "dot diagram" in your question?

Comment: @stewbasic there is no short definition given in the textbook. Dot diagram is used to find Jordan canonical form and basis in this book.

Comment: I don't think the statements hold for an arbitrary array of dots. For example let $k=m=2$ and put dots in positions $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$. Then $p_1=p_2=1$, so $p_1\geq p_2$, but $m\neq p_1$.

Comment: @stewbasic hmm.. are you familiar with dot diagram in the context of finding Jordan canonical form? In this case, is it possible to prove (a) and (b)?

Comment: I haven't seen the phrase before. We can't construct a proof without knowing what the starting assumptions are.